# How can I redirect a JSP to use HTTPS

Tags: ssl, tomcat, jsp, servlet

My web app is running, so that access to `/admin/login.jsp` happens over an unsecure HTTP connection.

I do not want to change web.xml file.

How can I change access to `/admin/login.jsp` from HTTP to HTTPS without editing the `web.xml` file?

Is there a way other than changing the `web.xml` file?

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? I don't get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Apache in front of Tomcat?

**Yes?** Well, that's easy.  Read my answer about redirecting HTTP to HTTPS [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/350372/forcing-ssl-in-apache-without-hard-coding-the-hostname).

**No?** Well, you should be.  Not only does Apache make an excellent reverse-proxy for Tomcat JSPs, but it also allows you to do things like rewriting URLs onto HTTPS, as well as caching with a number of modules for Apache.

**Quick answer:** Use apache, redirect /admin/login.jsp to HTTPS and use Apache to wrap everything up in a sexy little SSL transaction

Comment: i used standalone tomcat. do you mean is :<% Response.Redirect("https://www.example.com/admin/login.jsp") %> ? i Look for automatic way with once setting without editing jsp page?

Comment: Nono..  I mean if  you use apache in front of tomcat with mod_proxy or mod_jk, then you can use apache to wrap the requests in a SSL session